# How to execute different aws lambda depending on request body variable/item (aws api gateway)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to be able to execute different lambda based on a request parameter. How can I do this?

example:- If I have two aws lambdas **abc** and **pqr**, I want to send **lambda-function-name** parameter in request body (for a **POST** request). Depending on value of **lambda-function-name** I want to execute either **abc** or **pqr**?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately api gateway can only differentiate based on method and path.

A solution, however, would be to have a "proxy" lambda that inspected the POST body, invoked the desired lambda (using the aws-sdk; [documentation for node here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property)) and then returned the result.

Comment: Thanks Thomasmichalwallace, I liked your idea. that would work for me.